# React-Router-Dom (v6) not working / doesn't render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I try to render the "Home" component it just doesn't show anything... The path is correct, and the Router imports should be fine too. What am I missing? It worked on another project of mine and even if I copy and paste that code it doesn't seem to work.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./components/Home"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (

    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js:

```
import React from 'react'

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I expected the "Home" component to be rendered as soon as I load the page, but it wasn't (Blank page). I checked if I imported it incorrectly, but as soon as I delete the "Router" and "Routes" tags as well as the Route itself and just try to render the "Home" component on its own, it works.

It's probably something really small that I'm missing but I can't seem to figure it out right now.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code. What exact version of `react-router-dom` is installed? What are the exact steps to reproduce? How are you running the app?

Comment: react-router-dom version 6.4.3. It's basically just a brand new react app without the auto-generated app.css, App.test.js, logo.svg and setupTests.js.  Exept for react, react-dom and react-router-dom there is nothing else in the dependencies. I'm running the app over the npm start command, and my browser is Google Chrome.

Comment: I see, thanks for the information. Are there any errors in the terminal when building or the console when running? Could you try to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

Using Route requires Switch component which means you'll do the following:

```js
import React from "react";
import Home from "./components/Home"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Switch} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" >
        <Home/>
      </Route>
   </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I tried that but I got the error "export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'". I dont think Switches exist in v6.